# Wordpress Search - Normal pages has no link in search results

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I just realized on one of my pages, that the search results for normal pages (ie not posts or custom taxonomies) does not have a link to the page. I know it is caused by

```
<?php if( have_posts() ): while( have_posts() ): the_post();?>
```

Since I am only calling the posts. I am having trouble however understanding how to incorporate (which I assume) is get_pages into the mix, so it will work for both. So my question is, how would I make this work? something like ( have_posts() && ( get_pages() ) was my go-to, but it seems to not work. Any clue what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: where is the code until the closing `endwhile` ? or do you mean the pages do not appear in the query result?

Comment: The pages are shown just fine in the results - they are just not linked to the given page

Comment: Could you please share the full code snippet?